# Java GSON $type token

Tags: java, android, json, json.net, gson

I have some some Json string which is the return of a .Net WebAPI like this:

```
{ $type: "classType", "name": "someone there" }
```

The *$type* token is used by Json.Net to give a hint to (De)Serializer on what type it should use. In .net it works flawless so far...

Now we have a Java/Android client which uses *GSON* as the Json library.

So the problems are:

1. How to add *$type* to the serialized json string for each type?
2. How to make *GSON* to use this *$type* to choose to which java type to deserialize the string?

Thanks, I really appreciate any help in advice.

Best regards...